How to apply pointpillars on ROS2?
I am using pointpillars for 3D object detection on point cloud data (https://github.com/shangjie-li/pointpillars/tree/master). I have successfully trained and tested the model. I would like to apply the trained model for inference task using ROS2 (Humble). I need to create a (python) publisher and subscriber for this purpose. Is there any useful links/resources in this regard?
I appreciate any help in advance.
Thank you,
Abbas
